SwiftUI full-width button: Why 'maxWidth: .infinity'? Why not "minWidth: .infinity"?
I can accomplish a full-width button with the following code:
Button {
  print("Test, 123 ...")
}
label: {
  Text("Trigger Action")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  .frame(height: 50)
  .background(Color.blue)
  .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
  .cornerRadius(12)
}

It works fine.

But why "maxWidth: .infinity"?
Why isn't it "minWidth: .infinity"? That would make more sense to me.
Can someone explain, how the .frame-modifier works internally? And why it works the way it does

If the button really had a minimum width of "infinity", it would not look like that on the screenshot. That button has a finite width, which is less than "infinity". Is this just a problem of understanding English?

As Sweeper said, surely if the button had a minimum width of infinity it would be off the screen and you wouldn't see the corners.
In practice though it's a little different. I found this guide to be quite useful:
https://www.swiftuifieldguide.com/layout/flexible-frames/
